# Google API - Number of requests incorrect?

Tags: google-places-api

Trying to wrap my head around why this is the case...

Testing out the Google Places API. Yesterday I fired off one request, analyzed the JSON, prepared to parse and play with it. Today fired off a bunch more, keeping the 1000 free requests in mind, didn't go anywhere near it. Then bam - cut off, "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT".

Went to the console, and in the dashboard, the Places API says **132** requests. This looks about right. Went inside, looked at Quotas, it shows **1010** requests today, and **10** for *yesterday* (remember the 1 I did to check out the response). This looks entirely incorrect.

Before I run to Google and be all "why?", I thought I'd ask here first in case anyone has experienced this, or know if perhaps a single request actually ends up being multiple requests for some reason.

**EDIT**
... a search string like, "cn%20tower+toronto+canada" doesn't count as 3 queries....... does it??

Answer (score 3):

Answering myself here... found this in the docs:

> The Text Search service is subject to a 10-times multiplier. That is, each Text Search request that you make will count as 10 requests against your quota. If you've purchased the Google Places API Web Service as part of your Google Maps APIs Premium Plan contract, the multiplier may be different.

Well I'll be.

Comment: To add on to this, text searches take into account the number of characters/keystrokes used to calculate the number of requests/credits. [Usage rates and limits](https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/usage-limits)